# Retrieve data from firebase in react native app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-native

I am new to React native. I want to show the text which is fetched from firebase database on-app screen as text.
I have tried to print on console and alert and it is showing successfully but not on app screen.[firebase data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xijau.jpg) [console print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HV87C.jpg)  [alert box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wZCu.jpg)

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text,} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';


export default class ListItem extends Component {


  state= {
      items: []
   }


    componentWillMount(){
        var firebaseConfig = {
          apiKey: "***",
          authDomain: "***",
          databaseURL: "***",
          projectId: "***",
          storageBucket: "***",
          messagingSenderId: "***",
          appId: "***",
          measurementId: "***"
        };


        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

        var ref = firebase.database().ref('/14/info');

        ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {

        const userItem = snapshot.val();
        let items = Object.values(userItem);


        });
      }

render() {
        return (
            <View style= {{justifyContent: 'center'}}>

             <Text>{this.state.items}</Text> 
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Look like you have not posted your code properly. Please check and upload your code properly.

Comment: Three things: never take photos of a screen with a camera when you could just take a screenshot, never take screenshots of code, and never post code behind a link when you could just simply paste the code as text. The same applies to data and console outputs and everything else code-like.

Comment: This is my code and it works with alert and console but not in render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is loaded from Firebase (and pretty much any modern web API) asynchronously, since it may take some time to get the result. This means that when your app is rendered, the data isn't available yet. For this reason you need to tell React to re-render when the data is available, which you do by calling `setState()`.

```
let self = this;
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    const userItem = snapshot.val();
    let items = Object.values(userItem);
    self.setState({ items: items });
});
```

Alternatively you can use the fat arrow notation, to make this a bit simpler:

```
ref.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    const userItem = snapshot.val();
    let items = Object.values(userItem);
    this.setState({ items: items });
});
```

I **highly** recommend reading up on how to manage [state in a React application](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) before continuing, as this behavior is quite crucial to efficiently building React applications.